# style textblock button change text

Tags: wpf, button, binding, textblock

I want to change the TextBlock of a button programatically, but I still didn't get it right.

```
   <Style x:Key="RoundedButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Border CornerRadius="50" Background="#463190">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Tag}" Foreground="White" 
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"                                           
                                   Margin="0,0,0,0"                                       
                                   FontSize="20"/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: please, improve your post. it doesn't contains a question currently. "I still didn't get it right" doesn't explain what is a desired purpose and what is the problem

Comment: Please add more information on what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

`Button` controls has a property `Content` to show texts and no need to use `Tag`. It makes things are more complex.

If you change your `Binding` to the below, you will be able to use `Button`'s `Content` property to change the `Text` inside the `TextBlock`.

```
Text = "{Binding Path=Content, 
         RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Button}}"
```